# Convert column values to string and display in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a user model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   self.table_name = 'User'

end
```

User table has column status and it has values 0 and 1

I want to display status values in strings in json. when the user status is 0 then show inactive and active when its 1.

How can i create a method that'd do this conversion?

I'll call that method in controller and save result in instance variable and call that instance variable in view.

Thanks

Comment: `self.table_name = 'User'` - this violates few conventions at once :D

Comment: Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong? i am new to ruby on rails

Comment: Sure. First thing is that by convention the table name should be the plural form of the model name, which Rails will recognize automagically (you need  `self.table_name` only if you have the table name that does not follow the aforementioned). So to follow the conventions, your table name should be called `users` (lowecased, plural) and then you can remove the `self.table_name` altogether

Comment: Agreed, it is preferred to name your table `users` rather than `User`. This is the Rails convention and will save you a lot of headaches. Of course if you don't have control over your schema for some reason or you're building on to a legacy app, then setting the table_name like you've done is an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create an instance method that will return the string that you want:

```
def status_str
  case status
  when 0
    "active"
  when 1
    "archived"
  end
end
```

However a better way would be to use an [ActiveRecord Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
```

To make this work your `status` column would need to be an integer data type, not a boolean. See the [ActiveRecord Query Guide under Enums](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#enums) for more information.